# Image as background of div

Tags: image, html, background

I'm using http://www.paulvanroekel.nl/picasa/visuallightbox/ plugin, to create a gallery, actually works perfectly, but I have a problem with the blank spaces between images, cause by the different image dimensions, so I need to create something like this
https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BM-usuxCIAAthp9.jpg:large to keep the grid consistent between all the images.
The markup is:

```
<div>
  <a>
    <img>
  </a>
</div>
```

I try the @caramba solution resulting in this

http://jsfiddle.net/montogeek/x4PJ5/

How I can change the dimensions of the image to look consistent?

Comment: Please spend a minute clarifying your question. What have you tried? What's the problem? What's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this ?
http://jsfiddle.net/rzWKR/1/

```
<div class="img-box">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BM-usuxCIAAthp9.jpg:large" alt="" />
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .img-box {
    position:relative;
    border:solid 2px red;
    width:280px;height:250px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.img-box > img {
    position:absolute;
    left:-10px;
    top:-10px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your style :)